# pre-processor #defines and how to use globally without a pre-compiled header?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, precompiled-headers

The development I have done over the last few years uses a lot of pre-compiled headers. One for each product. The pre-compiled headers are used in a way to `#define` items that each product needs. This does keep the code rather clean and portable among each product.

But, how does one replicate this approach without using a pre-compiled header?

Basically, be able to `#define` a fair number of items and some basic includes, but have it not be a PCH.

Do you just create a `.h` and include this in every class that needs these defines?

can you just rename the `.pch` to a `.h`? Structurally it would look the same right? Well, plus a header quard.

UPDATE: This is a codebase that used to use Codewarrior for Mac and Win. Now uses XCode on OS X and We may be migrating to CMake for both Mac and Win to help us not have so many different environments.

Comment: The first one (just create a .h and include everywhere).

Comment: What are you `#define`ing these days?

Comment: @Alex Chamberlain - basically settings for each product. There about 8 products that use the same codebase and each product has a PCH for it that sets variables, paths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single include file (.h) and include it everywhere.

However, most build systems also provide a way to add `#defines` on a project scope.  For example, in Visual Studio, the *Preprocessor* section of the project properties allows you to place build-specific defines that are project wide.